# Parsing string into desired output

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Sample input is (note this is a one line string, I used a quote here to make it more readable):

> Level 1/129/1 Murray Ave & 15A&B ERICA AVENUE & 12 HARVEY STREET & 34
>   VICTORIA STREET & 3/56 ST LEONARDS ST, MOSMAN PARK ( John).  78/10
>   WELLINGTON ST MOSMAN PARK (Rambo)

My current output is:

```
1/129/1 - Murray - Ave - 
15A -  -  - 
B - ERICA - AVENUE - 
12 - HARVEY - STREET - 
34 - VICTORIA - STREET - 
3/56 - ST LEONARDS - ST - MOSMAN PARK
78/10 - WELLINGTON - ST - MOSMAN PARK
```

Desired output is:

```
1/129/1 - Murray - Ave - 
15A - ERICA - AVENUE - 
15B - ERICA - AVENUE - 
12 - HARVEY - STREET - 
34 - VICTORIA - STREET - 
3/56 - ST LEONARDS - ST - MOSMAN PARK
78/10 - WELLINGTON - ST - MOSMAN PARK
```

If the first property only contains the number, it should inherit the information from the next record and if the next record number only contains a letter it show backwards inherit the number of the previous record, for example:

```
    15A - Erica - Avenue
    15B - Erica - Avenue
```

**Which gives me the desired above output, how can I archive that ?**

Here is my code (NOTE: suffixes is a `List<string>`):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<ResultData> result = new List<ResultData>();
    string myColumn = "Level 1/129/1 Murray Ave & 15A&B ERICA AVENUE & 12 HARVEY STREET & 34 VICTORIA STREET & 3/56 ST LEONARDS ST, MOSMAN PARK ( John).  78/10 WELLINGTON ST MOSMAN PARK (Rambo)";
    // dot replaced with & as they are to be split
    myColumn = myColumn.Replace('.', '&');
    // I don't need the Level word which means 
    // each property starts with numbers now
    myColumn = myColumn.Replace("Level", "");
    // Removes anything in between parentheses and the parentheses
    myColumn = RemoveBetween(myColumn, '(', ')');

    string[] splitResult = myColumn.Split('&');    
    foreach (string item in splitResult)
    {
        string property = item.Trim();
        if (property.IndexOf(' ') > 0)
        {
            string area = string.Empty;
            string locationType = string.Empty;
            string number = property.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();
            property = property.Replace(number, "").Trim();

            // When comma is present, area is always the last
            // and locationType always before it
            if (property.IndexOf(',') > 0)
            {
                area = property.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last().Trim();
                property = property.Replace(area, "").Replace(",", "").Trim();

                locationType = property.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last().Trim();
                property = property.Replace(" " + locationType, "").Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                // When comma is not present I have to check
                // if the string contains a given street suffix
                // and pick up from there
                string found = suffixes.Find(x => property.Trim().Contains(" " + x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(found))
                    found = " " + found; 
                    // need the space otherwise it will delete 
                    // places like ST LEONARD.

                locationType = property.Substring(property.ToLower().IndexOf(found.ToLower()), found.Length).Trim();

                int total = property.ToLower().IndexOf(found.ToLower()) + found.Length;
                if (property.ToLower().IndexOf(found.ToLower()) > 0 && total < property.Length)
                    area = property.Substring(total, property.Length - total).Trim();

                property = property.Replace(",", "").Trim().Replace(locationType, "").Trim();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(area))
                    property = property.Replace(area, "").Trim();
            }

            string name = property;
            result.Add(new ResultData() { Number = number, Name = name, LocationType = locationType, Area = area });
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(new ResultData() { Number = property });
        }
    }

    string save = string.Empty;
    foreach (ResultData item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Number + " - " + item.Name + " - " + item.LocationType + " - " + item.Area);
        save += item.Number + " - " + item.Name + " - " + item.LocationType + " - " + item.Area + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"save.txt", save.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Press any key to leave...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

/// <summary>
/// Remove from the string the pattern and what is in between it 
/// more format double space to single
/// </summary>
static string RemoveBetween(string s, char begin, char end)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format("\\{0}.*?\\{1}", begin, end));
    return new Regex(" +").Replace(regex.Replace(s, string.Empty), " ");
}

public static bool Contains(this string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp)
{
    return source.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
}
```

**If you know anything I can do to improve the above code would love to know as well, write me a comment.**

Comment: Just to confirm, you are looking for a generic solution that will work for any sting based on these rules?

Comment: Do you have control to change the input

Comment: @psubsee2003 I am having only 1 issue which I can't solve right now see the `My current output is:` and `Desired output is:` I don't know how to fill up 15A with the data from the next entry and fill the number 15 to the data of it to produce the desired output. To put it simple, if an entry only have the number it should inherit the data from the next entry and if the next entry only have the letter on the number, it should inherit the number of the previous entry.

Comment: Why don't you just add a post-processing step where you check if any entry's number contains only a letter. If so, just copy and merge the previous record's data.

Comment: @NicoSchertler do you mean something like save the previous entry and compare with current entry for missing things ?

Comment: Either this way or another loop that checks the set after parsing it.

Comment: @NicoSchertler thanks I will try those options and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Apparently I cannot write comments in my answer. Thanks for the editing, Nico, but I might have done it myself (next time, wait at least 1 min). @Guapo my code performs the actions you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the job:

```
  string prevString = "";
  string[] splitResult = myColumn.Split('&');    
  foreach (string item in splitResult)
    {
        string property = item.Trim();
        if (property.IndexOf(' ') > 0)
        {
            string area = string.Empty;
            string locationType = string.Empty;
            string number = property.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();
            property = property.Replace(number, "").Trim();

            // When comma is present, area is always the last
            // and locationType always before it
            if (property.IndexOf(',') > 0)
            {
                area = property.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last().Trim();
                property = property.Replace(area, "").Replace(",", "").Trim();

                locationType = property.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last().Trim();
                property = property.Replace(" " + locationType, "").Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                // When comma is not present I have to check
                // if the string contains a given street suffix
                // and pick up from there
                string found = suffixes.Find(x => property.Trim().Contains(" " + x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(found))
                    found = " " + found; 
                    // need the space otherwise it will delete 
                    // places like ST LEONARD.

                locationType = property.Substring(property.ToLower().IndexOf(found.ToLower()), found.Length).Trim();

                int total = property.ToLower().IndexOf(found.ToLower()) + found.Length;
                if (property.ToLower().IndexOf(found.ToLower()) > 0 && total < property.Length)
                    area = property.Substring(total, property.Length - total).Trim();

                property = property.Replace(",", "").Trim().Replace(locationType, "").Trim();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(area))
                    property = property.Replace(area, "").Trim();
            }

                string name = property;
                if (prevString != "")
                {
                    result.Add(new ResultData() { Number = prevString, Name = name, LocationType = locationType, Area = area });
                    string numbersFromString = new String(number.Where(x => x >= '0' && x <= '9').ToArray());
                    if (numbersFromString == "")
                    {
                        string numbersFromString2 = new String(prevString.Where(x => x >= '0' && x <= '9').ToArray());
                        result.Add(new ResultData() { Number = (int)numbersFromString2 + number, Name = name, LocationType = locationType, Area = area });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.Add(new ResultData() { Number = number, Name = name, LocationType = locationType, Area = area });
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    result.Add(new ResultData() { Number = number, Name = name, LocationType = locationType, Area = area });
                }


                prevString = "";
        }
        else
        {
            prevString = property;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks Like each line starts with a space then a numeric.

So this might be a simpler first pass cleanup before you do any other processing.

```
       var myString = "Line: 12 this way 23 that way 34 no way".ToCharArray();
        var firstDigitFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++)
        {                
            var isNumber = char.IsNumber(myString[i]);
            if (isNumber && i > 0 && !firstDigitFound)
            {
                firstDigitFound = true;
                myString[i - 1] = '|';
            }
            else { firstDigitFound = false; }
        }

        var myNewArray = new string(myString).Split('|');
```

Comment: David that's not what need and no that would messed up all the numbers/entries.

Comment: very harsh for a mark down when some one tries to help. It also puts each number on a new line like you showed in your example. It should also be the first step in your processing

Comment: Appreciate your update but I still don't understand why you're trying to put every number on a new line that's not what I want. Carefully see **"My current output"** and **"Desired output"**

Comment: It puts every line that starts with a number on a new line as per your desired output.

Comment: David that's not what I am doing other wise I would not have on my desired output as above shown the following: `1/129/1 - Murray - Ave - `

Comment: Backslash is left out of above code, would need a fix. But this was a first pass cleanup.

Comment: Appreciate your help but we are talking about different books here, I have above the current output my code gives and a desired output and also outlined what is missing/wrong, you're not seeing that.